# Unitary $2 \times 2$ matrix - Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that every unitary $2 \times 2$ matrix has the form
\begin{bmatrix}
    a & -\overline{b} \\
    b & \overline{a} 
\end{bmatrix}
where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|^{2} + |b|^{2} = 1$

Assuming that $U$ is a unitary matrix, then it follows $$U^{*}U = I = UU^{*} $$
$$\pmatrix{x & y\\w & z}  \pmatrix{\overline{x} & \overline{w}\\\overline{y} & \overline{z}} = \pmatrix{1 & 0\\0 & 1}$$
which means
$$x\overline{x}+w\overline{w} = |x|^{2} + |w|^{2}= 1$$

From matrix multiplication above we also get the equations:
$$w\overline{x} + z\overline{y} = 0$$
$$x\overline{w} + y\overline{z} = 0 $$
I kept trying different substitutions, but I am still stuck at proving that $z = \overline{x}$ and $y = -\overline{w}$

Help?

Comment: "which means ...$|x|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$." I see how it means that $|x|^2 + |y|^2 = 1$ and $|w|^2 + |z|^2 = 1$, but I don't see $|x|^2 + |w|^2 = 1$ ... can you write out your logic for this part?

Comment: @JohnHughes Not necessarily the OP's rationale, but multiplying the matrices in the inverse order yields that result.

Comment: @JohnHughes multiplying in the inverse order, exactly, I just forgot to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$\pmatrix{\overline{x} & \overline{w} \\ \overline{y} & \overline{z}} = U^*= U^{-1} = \frac1{\det U}\pmatrix{z & -y \\ -w & x}$$

so $z = (\det U) \overline{x}$ and $y = -(\det U) \overline{w}$, where $\left|\det U\right| = 1$.

Indeed, $\det U$ can be any $\lambda$ with $|\lambda| = 1$, just consider $U = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda}$.

Answer (score 4):

You can't prove that because it is not true. All the matrices of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-\overline b\\b&\overline a\end{bmatrix}$$such that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ have determinant $1$. The unitary $2\times2$ matrices are of the form$$\begin{bmatrix}a&-\omega\overline b\\b&\omega\overline a\end{bmatrix},$$with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$ and $|\omega|=1$.

Comment: In particular, $\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & i}$ is unitary.

Comment: @JohnHughes Indeed!